# PHP foreach to nest list with variable elements at each level?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm still learning PHP, and have started to understand the working of foreach() loop. I am stuck on something.

I'm working with PHP drawing from a MySQL database, and I want to list how many items share the same "topic_id". With the initial number, I'm trying to make a nested list that identifies what different medium types each item is available in, and how many items are counted in each medium.

This is the database query I'm using:

```
SELECT 
  m.name AS medium, i.medium_id, f.name AS format, 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN it.topic_id = '$topicId' AND i.id = it.item_id 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 END
  ) AS sumFormat
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN item_topics AS it 
  ON i.id = it.item_id 
LEFT JOIN formats AS f 
  ON f.id = i.format_id 
LEFT JOIN media AS m 
  ON m.id = i.medium_id 
GROUP BY medium, format 
ORDER BY medium ASC
```

This gives the following result (I've omitted sumFormat=0 results):

```
+--------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| medium       | medium_id   | format       | sumFormat |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| Games        |           1 | NULL         |         1 |
| Magazines    |           2 | Paperback    |        35 |
| Albums       |           3 | CD           |        25 |
| Albums       |           3 | Record       |         1 |
| Books        |           5 | Audiobook    |        38 |
| Books        |           5 | Diary        |         1 |
| Books        |           5 | Dictionary   |         4 |
| Books        |           5 | Ebook        |       421 |
| Books        |           5 | Hardback     |        76 |
| Books        |           5 | Paperback    |       574 |
| Comics       |           6 | Paperback    |         2 |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Depending on the "$topicId" being queried, the results will be different - in some cases, there might not be any items in a given medium or format. I'd like the PHP code to handle this, so only the medium types and formats that are present for the "topic_id" will be listed.

In my PHP code, I've put it together like so:

```
<ul id="formats">
<?php foreach ($topicFormats as $topicFormat): ?>
    <?php if ($topicFormat['medium'] && $topicFormat['sumFormat']): ?>
        <li><?= $topicFormat['medium'] ?></li>
            <?php if ($topicFormat['sumFormat']): ?>
                <ul>
                <li><?= $topicFormat['sumFormat'] ?>
                    <?php if (!$topicFormat['format']): ?>
                        Games
                    <?php else: ?><?= $topicFormat['format'] ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The final HTML looks like this:

```
    1178 Items
    • Games
        • 1 Games
    • Magazines
        • 35 Paperback
    • Albums
        • 1 Record
    • Albums
        • 25 CD
    • Books
        • 38 Audiobook
    • Books
        • 1 Diary
    • Books
        • 4 Dictionary
    • Books
        • 421 Ebook
    • Books
        • 76 Hardback
    • Books
        • 574 Paperback
    • Comics
        • 2 Paperback
```

However I *want* the result below:

```
    1178 Items
    • Games
        • 1 Games
    • Magazines
        • 35 Paperback
    • Albums
        • 1 Record
        • 25 CD
    • Books
        • 38 Audiobook
        • 1 Diary
        • 4 Dictionary
        • 421 Ebook
        • 76 Hardback
        • 574 Paperback
    • Comics
        • 2 Paperback
```

I have checked this issue on StackOverFlow but did not find any solution.
Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:** I haven't had a chance to try out any of your suggestions yet, but in answer to **Kapilgopinath**, here is the resultant array (I think this is what you're asking for - I've never retrieved a resultant array before!):

```
Array 
(
[0] => Games
[medium] => Games
[1] => 1 
[medium_id] => 1 
[2] => 
[format] => 
[3] => 1 
[sumFormat] => 1 
)
```

("Games" doesn't have a format, so it returns null - that would be where other medium types would list "Paperback", "CD", etc.)

Comment: So the medium should be out of the main foreach block

Comment: @RakeshSharma hoq this would help ?!

Comment: I would just only put out the ul tag in the loop if the value of medium has changed.

Comment: This is possible by grouping the resultant array. Can you paste the resultant $topicFormats array.

Comment: @Kapilgopinath I've added the resultant array (I hope I did it right!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with using a 'foreach' loop is that the next read is not done until the end of the loop, which is too late, when you have a 'nested loop' as here. It can be easier, although not less code, to use a 'read ahead' technique. The advantage is that you do not need an if test to determine what to do with the current entry. Therefore you need an iterator then it is just nested loops. With the read of the next record, immediately after the current one has been processed.

```
<?php
    $values_from_db = array( array( 'medium' => 'Games', 'format' => 'Games', 'sumFor' => 1, ), array( 'medium' => 'Magazines', 'format' => 'Paperback', 'sumFor' => 35, ), array( 'medium' => 'Albums', 'format' => 'CD', 'sumFor' => 25, ), array( 'medium' => 'Albums', 'format' => 'Record', 'sumFor' => 1, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Audiobook', 'sumFor' => 38, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Diary', 'sumFor' => 1, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Dictionary', 'sumFor' => 4, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Ebook', 'sumFor' => 421, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Hardback', 'sumFor' => 76, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Paperback', 'sumFor' => 574, ), array( 'medium' => 'Comics', 'format' => 'Paperback', 'sumFor' => 2, ), );

    $iterSumFor = new ArrayIterator($values_from_db);
    $curEntry = $iterSumFor->current(); // read ahead -- always a current record to process
?>
<ul>
<?php while ($iterSumFor->valid()): ?>
    <?php $curMedium = $curEntry['medium']; ?>
    <li><?= $curMedium ?></li>
    <ul>
        <?php while ($iterSumFor->valid() && $curEntry['medium'] == $curMedium): ?>
            <li><?= $curEntry['sumFor'], '&nbsp;', $curEntry['format'] ?></li>
            <?php $iterSumFor->next(); ?>
            <?php $curEntry = $iterSumFor->current(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endwhile ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I really appreciate this answer, because it has taught me something new altogether. I have a question, however: this gave the results perfectly, but so did the "foreach" approach that kevinabelita provided. Which, then, is "better"? Does one of these two methods have an advantage over the other?

Comment: @Dion, The way to think about it isn't about 'better' or 'best'. It it more that you now have two separate ways of solving a problem that are: 1) similar amounts of code to implement 2) easy to understand and 3) give the correct results. You choose the appropriate way depending on the problem you are trying to solve. Sometime 'read ahead' is easier to use, other times 'foreach'. Both have their uses. 'Read ahead' is usually easier when there are 'nested' loops and the input is a single stream.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to group the main result of the query first. And from then on, you can loop them and build the list. Here is the general idea, consider this example:

```
$values_from_db = array( array( 'medium' => 'Games', 'format' => 'Games', 'sumFor' => 1, ), array( 'medium' => 'Magazines', 'format' => 'Paperback', 'sumFor' => 35, ), array( 'medium' => 'Albums', 'format' => 'CD', 'sumFor' => 25, ), array( 'medium' => 'Albums', 'format' => 'Record', 'sumFor' => 1, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Audiobook', 'sumFor' => 38, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Diary', 'sumFor' => 1, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Dictionary', 'sumFor' => 4, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Ebook', 'sumFor' => 421, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Hardback', 'sumFor' => 76, ), array( 'medium' => 'Books', 'format' => 'Paperback', 'sumFor' => 574, ), array( 'medium' => 'Comics', 'format' => 'Paperback', 'sumFor' => 2, ), );

// group them first
$formatted_array = array();
foreach($values_from_db as $key => $value) {
    $formatted_array[$value['medium']][] = $value;
}

$list = '<ul>';
foreach($formatted_array as $key => $value) {
    $list .= "<li>$key</li>";
    if(is_array($value)) {
        $list .= "<ul>";
        foreach($value as $index => $element) {
            $list .= "<li>$element[sumFor] $element[format]</li>";
        }
        $list .= "</ul>";
    }
}
$list .= '</ul>';

print_r($list);
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kcr1qj)

Comment: Thank you for this answer - it did give the results, as did Ryan Vincent's answer, which used the "read ahead" technique. Since I'm still learning PHP, is the "read ahead" technique a better overall approach, instead of doing foreach loops?

Answer (score 0):

Doing this by saving the previous value of medium and only outputting the  tag when this changes would give something like this (not tested)

```
<ul id="formats">
<?php 
$prev_medium = '';
foreach ($topicFormats as $topicFormat)
{
    if ($topicFormat['medium'] && $topicFormat['sumFormat'])
    {
        if ($prev_medium != $topicFormat['medium'])
        {
            if ($prev_medium != '')
            {
                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
            echo '<li>'.$topicFormat['medium'].'</li>';
            echo '<ul>';
            $prev_medium = $topicFormat['medium'];
        }
        if ($topicFormat['sumFormat'])
        {
            echo '<li>'.$topicFormat['sumFormat'];
            echo (($topicFormat['format']) ? $topicFormat['format'] : 'Games' );
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
}
if ($prev_medium != '')
{
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

In a relatively simple list like this it might be easy to do as Kapil gopinath suggests and group the items in SQL, then just explode them out in the code.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$i =0; $a = array();
<ul id="formats">
<?php foreach ($topicFormats as $topicFormat): ?>
    <?php if ($topicFormat['medium'] && $topicFormat['sumFormat']): ?>
        <li><?php  if(!in_array($topicFormat['medium'], $a)) {
                      $a[$topicFormat['medium']]= $topicFormat['medium'];
                      echo $a[$topicFormat['medium']];
                    }?></li>
            <?php if ($topicFormat['sumFormat']): ?>
                <ul>
                <li><?= $topicFormat['sumFormat'] ?>
                    <?php if (!$topicFormat['format']): ?>
                        Games
                    <?php else: ?><?= $topicFormat['format'] ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this.    


<?php foreach ($topicFormats as $topicFormat): ?>
        <?php 
        $medium = $topicFormat['medium'];
        $format = $topicFormat['format']          
        $format[$medium][] = $topicFormat['sumFormat'].' '. $format ? $format : 'Games'; 
        <?php endforeach;        
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($arr);
?>
```